# How to combine and sort multiple OrderedDict in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

The below data's are from from three different Django Serializer  outputs

```
post=[{"title" :"abc", "date" : "10-03-2021"}, {"title" :"xyz", "date" : "28-01-2021"}, ......]

comments=[{"comment_text" :"heloo", "date" : "31-05-2021"}, {"comment_text" :"heloo", "date" : "20-04-2021"}, ......]

friends=[{"friend" :"abc", "date" : "12-03-2021"}, {"friend" :"xyz", "date" : "10-05-2021"}, ......]
```

Now I want to combine all three in to single output element and sorted it by date.
it is possible??

tried the below code it throws , cannot add orderddict to a list.

```
l=post+comments+friends
l.sort(key='date', reverse=True)
```

Comment: Of course it's possible. You'd concatenate the lists, then use e.g. `.sort()` on it.

Comment: when I tried o concatenate it throws "cannot add orderddict to a list ", I am bit new to django , can you help me in this

Comment: Maybe you should show the code you've tried, first.

Comment: test code added to the question

Comment: [This is the answer i was looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71448141/how-to-serialize-multiple-model-object)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
combined_list = post + comments + friends

sorted_lilist = sorted(combined_list, key=lambda k: k['date'])
```

In case you need reverse order, just add `reverse=True` arg to `sorted` function.

Comment: This is a good start, but due to the dates being in dd-mm-yyyy format, it's probably not what OP wants in the end. (That said, they should use ISO 8601 yyyy-mm-dd dates anyway...)

Comment: will throw this error cannot add orderddict to a list. ??

Comment: @Sergey Pugach it throws  < not supported in instance of datetime.datetime and str