# How to combine and load data in django like this?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, python-3.8

this is my models

```
class model1(models.Model):
    name = models.charField()

class model2(models.Model):
    model1 = models.Foriegnkey(model1)
    id = models.IntegerField(primarykey=True)
    title = models.charFiled()
```

I wanted some thing like this

```
{"model_name1":[{"id":1,"title":"title1"},{"id":2,"title":"title2"}],
 "model_name2":[{"id":3,"title":"title1"},{"id":4,"title":"title2"}],}
```

how to achieve this in django, the effiecient way

Comment: Through a serializer.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: [This is the answer i was looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71448141/how-to-serialize-multiple-model-object)

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    {
        "model": "app_name.model_name1",
        "fields": { "title": "title1" }
    },
    {
        "model": "app_name.model_name1",
        "fields": { "title": "title2" }
    },
    {
        "model": "app_name.model_name2",
        "fields": { 
            "title": "title1"
            }
    },
    {
        "model": "app_name.model_name2",
        "fields": { 
            "title": "title2"
         }
    }
]
```

Just add the column name and it's value inside the fields. and you don't really need to add "id", it will created by django.

Comment: how to get this automatically